# How to handle optional items

Tags: c#, collections

I have about 9 checkboxes in which allows you to pick what items  are available for a future function.  I then want to call my function to pick a random one of these items X% of the time (X being set by a constant, to determine how often this should happen), one an item is picked, it needs to be pulled from the list so it is not chosen again the next time we need to call foo().

I was thinking I would iterate through the check boxes initially, and add the ones available to a list.  I would do a random to determine if I should pull an item, and then pull it from the list then remove the list item.

Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes this is the best way to do it.  You don't need to worry about percentages - just pick a random number between 0 and the size of the list.

Comment: Err, actually, I wouldn't put checkboxes in a list - I'd put the data that corresponds to the options that those check boxes represent in a list.  Like: `new List<string> { "Orange", "Blue", "Green" };`.  Build the check box from that data once you've chosen it to be presented to the user.  Minor difference, but it would keep you from having a bunch of check boxes floating around in memory that you didn't need.

Comment: Yeah, I as planning on just using a marker, the checkbox object, but thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: I would have liked to accept your answer as you answered first, but some how I can't seem to do that as it isn't under the answers so I accepted JDRoss.

Comment: I voted to close this question (the FAQ suggests you not ask questions when you already have a good answer and are simply soliciting opinion - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), so I didn't think it was fair for me to add this as an answer.  When I realized I had more to add than "yes, that's the right way to do it", it was too late to revoke my close vote, so I still thought I should keep to comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a collection that references check boxes. randomly select from this collection and once selected remove it.  This way you won't reuse the same check box.

Comment: Thanks Jdross, So similar to how I mentioned using a list?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:
1) Don't get your UI mixed in with your business logic.
2) You can build a better solution with a collection and a DataTemplate, something like this:

C#

```
public class ThingType : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public string ThingName { get; set; }

    private bool thingAvailable;
    public bool ThingAvailable { get { return thingAvailable; } set { thingAvailable = value; PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ThingAvailable")); } }
}

public class MainVM 
{
    public ObservableCollection<ThingType> MyThings { get; set; }


    public MainVM()
    {
        MyThings = new ObservableCollection<ThingType>();
        MyThings.Add(new ThingType() { ThingName = "thing 1" });
        MyThings.Add(new ThingType() { ThingName = "thing 2" });
    }

    public ThingType GetRandomThing()
    {
        var availableThings = MyThings.Where(x => x.ThingAvailable == true).ToArray();
        int randomThingIndex = new Random().Next(availableThings.Length - 1);
        availableThings[randomThingIndex].ThingAvailable = false;
        return availableThings[randomThingIndex];
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="thingTemplate">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding ThingName}" IsChecked="{Binding ThingAvailable, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,56,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MyThings}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource thingTemplate}" Width="120" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,195,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```